# How to provide MapStruct Mapping annotation mapping meta data at runtime

Tags: java, annotations, java-bytecode-asm, mapstruct, annotation-processing

We use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) between a *business-model* and our *ui-model*.
When a UI client wants to get sorted data, it can specify a field from the *ui-model*.
Our `MapStructParser` can get the corresponding *business-model* field-name and create the needed Criteria to sort it.

**Example:**

```java
public interface ModelMapping extends BridgeMapping<BusinessModel, UiModel> {
   @Mapping(source = "zip", target = "plz")
   UiModel modelToUiModel(BusinessModel model, @MappingTarget UiModel uiModel);
}
```

**The Problem:**
How to read the `@Mapping(source = "zip", target = "plz")` annotation and get the `source` and `target` value?
The `Mapping`-Annotation has `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, so it's not possible to access it via reflections.

Comment: I've made the edit, but for your reference, [java-bytecode-asm] is the tag for Java bytecode, not [assembly]. I'd also suggest adding the [java] tag, but that will require removing another tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solved this problem by using [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) (bytecode manipulation and analysis framework)
to read the `Mapping`-Annotation and provide it in a meta model:

**Example** (Also [available on Github](https://github.com/TobseF/mapstruct-metadata-example))

```java
public class AnnotationParser {
   public void parse(Class<?> mapper) {
      ClassInfoCollector classPrinter = new ClassInfoCollector(annotationInfos);
      ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(mapper.getCanonicalName());
      cr.accept(classPrinter, 0);
   }
}

public class ClassInfoCollector extends ClassVisitor {

   private final List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser;

   public ClassInfoCollector(List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser) {
      super(ASMversion);
      this.mapStructParser = mapStructParser;
   }

   @Override
   public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
      super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
   }

   @Override
   public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String methodName, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
      return new MethodInfoCollector(methodName,  mapStructParser);
   }

}

public class ClassInfoCollector extends ClassVisitor {

   private final List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser;

   public ClassInfoCollector(List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser) {
      super(ASMversion);
      this.mapStructParser = mapStructParser;
   }

   @Override
   public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
      super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
   }

   @Override
   public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String methodName, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
      return new MethodInfoCollector(methodName,  mapStructParser);
   }

}

class MethodInfoCollector extends MethodVisitor {

    private final String methodName;
    private final List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser;

   public MethodInfoCollector(String method, List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser) {
      super(ASMversion);
      this.methodName = method;
      this.mapStructParser = mapStructParser;
   }

   @Override
   public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String descriptor, boolean visible) { 
      return new MethodAnnotationInfoCollector(methodName, descriptor,  mapStructParser);
   }
}

class MethodAnnotationInfoCollector extends AnnotationVisitor {

   private final String method;
   private final String annotationType;
   private final List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser;

   public MethodAnnotationInfoCollector(String method, String annotationType, List<MethodAnnotationInfo> mapStructParser) {
      super(ASMversion);
      this.method = method;
      this.annotationType = annotationType;
      this.mapStructParser = mapStructParser;
   }

   @Override
   public void visit(String name, Object value) {
      MethodAnnotationInfo annotationInfo = new MethodAnnotationInfo(method,  annotationType, name, value.toString());
      mapStructParser.add(annotationInfo);
      super.visit(name, value);
   }

}
```

Wit this `AnnotationParser` it's possible to get the mapping info in this way:

```java
class BusinessModel{
   String zip; 
}

class UiModel{
   String plz; 
}

public interface ModelMapping extends BridgeMapping<BusinessModel, UiModel> {
   @Mapping(source = "zip", target = "plz")
   UiModel modelToUiModel(BusinessModel model, @MappingTarget UiModel uiModel);
}

@Test
public testMappingInfo(){
   MapStructParser mappingInfo = new MapStructParser();
   mappingInfo.parseMappingInterface(ModelMapping.class);
   assertEquals("zip", mappingInfo.mapToTargetField("plz"));
}
```

The `mappingInfo.mapToTargetField("plz")` returns the mapped field of if the `BusinessModel` (`zip`).
The `AnnotationParser` is a general purpose annotation parser which provide a list of `MethodAnnotationInfo`.
The `MapStructParser` uses the `AnnotationParser` model to build a `MapStructMappingInfo` by collecting the `Mapping`-Annotations.

The full runnable and tested example is available in here:
https://github.com/TobseF/mapstruct-metadata-example

> Theoretically it also possible to hook into the MapStruct annotation processing process and generate MetaModel Java classes (`ModelElementProcessor`). But I wasn't able to get it working. Adding additional Annotation processors is't straight forward and debugging Annotation processing during class compilation is more than cumbersome. Four our purpose the ASM way and a simple mapping is sufficient.